# How to make the last item of a list always in the same place (the rest going up), to show images instead of URLs, to make an app based on a website?

Tags: express, web-applications, socket.io, instant-messaging

Please can you answer the following questions?
I'm currently using
 - NodeJS - Express
 - Socket.IO
 - JQuery
 - W3.CSS

- I have a chat web/mobile (mobile just means responsive) app using the same website, but it is not enough. The mobile version should be able to notify and be as the native versions (fast and responsive). How could I do that?
  **How to make a native app based on a website?**
- My webchat looks like a mix of IRC and IM messengers. I'd like it to be full IM : the messages appear by making the window going down, and I prefer that the messages go up.
  **How to arrange a ul list (li can be infinite) so the last and new message stays the last and the rest goes up (eventually hides too)?**
- How could I enable the direct transmission of images in which we don't have to click on a link but we directly see it? I saw one document on it but it looked old.
  **How to directly see images by entering an image URL?**

I'd also like it to be pretty fast!
I might use postgres as database with Heroku.
You can find an appendice of the app here : https://njstesting.herokuapp.com (free testing plan - I'm a teenager)

Thank you for all your attention :-)

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow - there are too many answers or would require an excessive answer. Please refine the question into one, non-open ended question. See the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on what to avoid in a question and what [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you can ask about.

Comment: I've updated hoping it is now precise enough :-) @AshleyB

Comment: This is still 3 questions bundled into 1 really. You have loads of ways to create an app based on a website, just to name a few - [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/). Question 2, would need HTML & CSS and probably JavaScript, generally you would provide some code and state what you have tried so far, and what the intended behaviour is.

Comment: Question 3 is a little vague, you will need to look at something like express-static (for serving static files), or write your own alternative. You can do it in express manually(ish) using `res.sendFile`.